# what is the different jpox and data nucleus implementation of JDO?

Tags: java, jdo

what is the different jpox and data nucleus implementation of JDO?  both also free implementation right?

Answer (score 2):

JPOX is no longer developed and hasn't been for 18 months. DataNucleus replaced it.